# filter for value on groups data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I'm looking to filter a `data.table` for a max value on groups.

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = c(1L, 2L),
                 V2 = LETTERS[1:3],
                 V3 = round(rnorm(4), 4),
                 V4 = 1:12)

 V1 V2     V3     V4
 1:  1  A -0.1346  1
 2:  2  A  0.2309  4
 3:  1  A  0.7067  7
 4:  2  A -1.0082 10
 5:  2  B -1.0082  2
 6:  1  B -0.1346  5
 7:  2  B  0.2309  8
 8:  1  B  0.7067 11
 9:  1  C  0.7067  3
10:  2  C -1.0082  6
11:  1  C -0.1346  9
12:  2  C  0.2309 12
```

I've tried this but no dice:

```
DT[,max(V3), by =.(V2)]

   V2     V1
1:  A 1.2281
2:  B 1.2281
3:  C 1.2281
```

Short of a loop, how would I approach this? I prefer a data.table method.

Comment: What's the issue? Everything seems to be working as intended. When you create your data table, it will have size 12 (because of V4), but you have 4 random values and 3 letters, therefore the values will repeat themselves, making it so the maximum for each letter will always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

We can create a row index to subset the dataset

```
DT[DT[, .I[V3 == max(V3)], by = V2]$V1]
```

If there is only single max element for each 'V2'

```
DT[DT[, .I[which.max(V3)], by = V2]$V1]
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in the second line of code. It should be `DT[DT[, .I[which.max(V3)], by = V2]$V1]`, right?